# Segmentation error in php extension when using pthread_detach

Tags: php, c++

i wrote a php extension with c++ , it compiled and installed

i use thread , when i use pthread_detach and php script stop running it say  Segmentation fault

i also tryed PHPCPP and also get same error

i want php script stop running but my thread in php extension continue to work

i test in php 74 and 72

this is my code

c++ code

```
#include <php.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//g++ -shared -o telircoampq.so $(php-config --includes) telircoamq.cpp -fPIC -g $(php-config --libs)
//cp telircoampq.so /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/telircoampq.so
// php74 -d extension=telircoampq.so davari.php
// Function that will be run in the background thread
static void* background_function(void* arg) {
  // Cast the argument back to its original type
  std::pair<std::string, std::string>* args = static_cast<std::pair<std::string, std::string>*>(arg);

  // Do something with the arguments...
  std::string queue = args->first;
  std::string data = args->second;

  // Clean up the argument pair
  delete args;
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("/var/www/c/test/test.mohsen");
  // Exit the thread
  //pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// PHP function that creates a background thread and passes two arguments to it
PHP_FUNCTION(do_my_job) {
  // Parse the function arguments
  char* queue;
  size_t queue_len;
  char* data;
  size_t data_len;
    int result;
  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &queue, &queue_len, &data, &data_len) == FAILURE) {
    RETURN_NULL();
  }

  // Create a pair of arguments to pass to the background function
  std::pair<std::string, std::string>* args = new std::pair<std::string, std::string>(std::string(queue, queue_len), std::string(data, data_len));

  // Create a new thread to run the background function
  pthread_t thread;
  result =pthread_create(&thread, NULL, background_function, static_cast<void*>(args));

    pthread_detach(thread);

  // Return the queue value to the PHP user
  //RETURN_STRING(queue);

   if (result != 0) {
        // Handle error
        // ...
    }

    // Return the thread ID to the PHP function
    RETURN_LONG((long)thread);


}

// Extension initialization function
zend_function_entry telircoampq_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(do_my_job, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

static PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(telircoampq)
{
    zend_register_functions(NULL, telircoampq_functions, NULL, MODULE_PERSISTENT);
    return SUCCESS;
}

// Extension entry point
zend_module_entry telircoampq_module_entry = {
  STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
  "TelircoTest",
  NULL,
  PHP_MINIT(telircoampq),
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  "1.0",
  STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

// Extension initialization function
ZEND_GET_MODULE(telircoampq)
```

with PHPCPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <phpcpp.h>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void TelircoBack(const std::string& queue_name, const std::string& json_str)
{

    std::string file_path = "/var/www/c" + queue_name;
    std::ofstream file(file_path);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        file << json_str;
        file.close();
    }
}

Php::Value insert_json_to_queue(Php::Parameters& params)
{
    std::string queue_name = params[0];
    std::string json_str = params[1];


    // Call the TelircoBack function in a separate thread
 std::thread t(TelircoBack, queue_name, json_str);
 t.detach();
    return queue_name;
}

extern "C" {
    PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() 
    {
        static Php::Extension extension("TelircoAMPQ", "1.0");

        // Register the insert_json_to_queue function
        extension.add<insert_json_to_queue>("insert_json_to_queue", {
            Php::ByVal("queue_name", Php::Type::String),
            Php::ByVal("json_str", Php::Type::String)
        });

        return extension.module();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use both `pthread_t` and `std::thread` in a single app?

Comment: Fire up the ol' debugger on the calling process and place a breakpoint in your functions. Trigger the events that call your functions, start stepping and gathering intel.

Comment: Regarding `static void* background_function(void* arg)` You have to keep that promise of a returned `void*` even if you never use it. If you standardize on `std::thread` you can swap to `static void background_function(void* arg)` and it becomes a non-problem.

Comment: Recommendation: Do the `if (result != 0) { // Handle error }` before you `pthread_detach(thread);`. If anything went wrong and you don't have a valid thread to detach.

Comment: detaching threads is a sure way to get into trouble anyway, do NOT use detach.
I've use threads extensively for over 20 years and never needed detach anyway, what  makes you think it is a good idea to use it?
You should always be able to synchronize shutdown of your threads, e.g. make sure they stopped (by calling std::thread::join) before you delete any object the threads have access to. Or by sending a thread a stop signal (condition_variable) and waiting for it to stop.

Comment: i need to stop php , do you have any other suggestion to use instead of detaching ?

Comment: Return a handle, something that the PHP side can hold onto and the C++ side can use to identify the thread, from the functions that start threads. Then have the PHP side call a C++ function with the handle to ask the thread to stop and then join the thread. Perhaps add a timeout to kill the whole ball of wax if you've got a bug and the thread doesn't respond to a polite shutdown request. You use a similar tactic when there is any resource that needs to be disposed of on the C++ side, closing a file, returning a memory allocation, returning the robot arm to a safe position, etc....